# Can i make XMLHttpRequest from a Windows Phone 8 HTML 5 APP?

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8

i'm currently working on a rough draft for a HTML5/JS/CSS based App for Windows Phone 8. As far as i understand i can build a HTML5 App in the Browser and pretty much drop it into visual studio, do some magic and get a Windows Phone 8 App. Awesome.

The app that im going to make is basically a nicer content view for some data i get from the Web. I have some web-dev experience and the following concerns me:

I can't make a XMLHttpRequest to another domain in a normal browser. I.e: i can't load a website from say google.com and have that site make a request to bing.com. However in a Phone App where my Website gets loaded from the localhost/the app itself, can i make a request to another domain to retrieve the data i want to show using JavaScript?

thx for your help